# In SQL Server, how can I execute a piece of tsql against all databases in an instance?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

In SQL Server, how can I execute a piece of tsql against all databases in an instance?

Great thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an undocumented stored procedure `sp_MSForEachDB` which if you call passing in a string as a parameter, it will execute that string, substituting a `?` for the database name.

E.g.:

```
exec sp_MSForEachDB 'use ?; select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
```

Comment: +1 - this is why I spend time on SO, to find out little snippets like this!

Comment: +1, this works in 2000, 2005 and 2008. Also note the `sp_MSForEachtable`

Answer (score 2):

For SQl Server 2005, the excellent [SSMS Tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=5) contains this functionality.

[This functionality is available natively in SQL Server 2008].